# How to convert string into equation and solve it in Perl?

Tags: perl

I have equation stored as string in a variable. I want to convert that string into equation and solve it using the values I have.
Can someone help me how to approach this problem? How to understand equation stored in string and put values in it. For example in code I have following information,

```
$eq = "(a+b)*c";
$a = "4";
$b = "1";
$c = "2";
```

I want output of this as 10 which is solution of equation.

Comment: Not sure this is an exact duplicate as the equation can't be directly evaled

Comment: For general text parsing in Perl, see for example: [Regexp::Grammars](https://metacpan.org/pod/Regexp::Grammars) or [Marpa::R2](https://metacpan.org/pod/Marpa::R2)